# Nashorn put compiledsript into engine scope

Tags: java, nashorn, scriptengine

I have two js files,

- one is js library
- second one is a simple script usually somewhat around 50 lines, that needs to access functions from the library.

In my project im trying to precompile all javascripts during my application startup, and then at runtime only invoke CompiledScripts with desired parameters.

I ended up with the following code

```
    static String LIBRARY = "function hello(arg) {return 'Hello ' + arg;};";

    static String SCRIPT = "hello(arg)";

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Nashorn");
        Compilable compilable = ((Compilable) engine);
        CompiledScript compiledLib = compilable.compile(LIBRARY);
        compiledLib.eval();

        CompiledScript actualScript = compilable.compile(SCRIPT);

        Bindings helloParams = new SimpleBindings();
        helloParams.put("arg","world");
        ScriptObjectMirror result = (ScriptObjectMirror) actualScript.eval(helloParams);
        System.out.println(result);
}
```

But this code throws an error

```
> compiledScript.eval(helloParams);
<eval>:1 ReferenceError: "hello" is not defined
```

How can i access context of "compiledLib" (ie methods and variables) from within the "actualScript"?

Comment: Who cares about Nashorn? It's discontinued and almost everybody today uses either GraalJS or Rhino these days.

Comment: Not every application is suitable to be upgraded above jdk 8, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling doesn't register the `hello()` function, it just parses the JavaScript code.

You need to *execute* the code for the function to be registered.

Remember, in JavaScript, there is very little difference between these two statements, except that `function` declarations are hoisted and can therefore be used before the declaration statement:

```js
function hello(arg) {return 'Hello ' + arg;};

var hello = function(arg) {return 'Hello ' + arg;};
```

There is therefore little reason to separately compile the LIBRARY code, you just run it and save off all the created global variables, which are the library methods. E.g. after executing your LIBRARY code, you'll have a global variable named `hello`.

---

```java
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Nashorn");
Compilable compilable = ((Compilable) engine);

// Process LIBRARY code
Bindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
engine.eval(LIBRARY, bindings);

// Compile SCRIPT code
CompiledScript actualScript = compilable.compile(SCRIPT);

// Run SCRIPT code
bindings.put("foo", "world");
Object result = actualScript.eval(bindings);
System.out.println(result);
```

*Output*

```
Hello world
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however if im reading your code correctly you are not actually precompiling the library.

Comment: @user2749903 No, why would I? I would only ever run it once. The resulting bindings, with all the registered functions, is what you save, not the compile LIBRARY script.